# Source code for the "nameof" operator of C#

Tags: c#, .net

Where can I get the source code for "nameof" of C# or how do I decompile it?

I checked https://referencesource.microsoft.com/, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 9):

It's not something you can decompile as such, or show you source code for. It's part of the C# compiler: when you use `nameof(Foo)` the compiler just injects "Foo" into the source code. The IL for the methods is *exactly* the same:

```
static void PrintMyName()
{
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(PrintMyName));
}
```

vs

```
static void PrintMyName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("PrintMyName");
}
```

As noted in comments, it's not just that the name is taken literally as per the operand; it's the last part of the name that's used. So for example, if you have:

```
string x = "10";
string text = nameof(x.Length);
```

then that will resolve to "Length". (This doesn't use the value of `x` at execution time, either - it's fine if `x` is null. Or you could use `nameof(string.Length)` or `nameof(String.Length)`.)

Comment: Exactly. It only exists to allow refactoring tools to easily adjust such name references too. For example, if you rename `Foo` to `Bar`, it’s easy to also adjust `nameof(Foo)` to `nameof(Bar)`. But with a string containing “Foo”, it’s far less certain it should be adjusted to contain “Bar” instead.

Comment: It’s also worth noting it will only stringify the symbol, not its qualification. So `nameof(Initech.Flair.Foo)` compiles to just “Foo”.

Comment: @Zastai: Well it's more than just for refactoring tools. It prevents typos even if you never change the name. It's a compile-time-safe way of referring to something.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the functionality of "nameof". I am curious to know how the compiler does it i.e. what programming code is done. Can I make such an operator, if needed? Please don't give solution based on "Expression", I am aware of it.

Comment: @Bibin: No, you can't write your own operator, unless you want to fork and modify the compiler. (You can do that, but I wouldn't recommend it.) If you want to see exactly what the compiler does, you can look at the Roslyn source code at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn, but I'm not sure you'll learn anything *interesting* about it - and given the complexities of Roslyn, I suspect you'll spend quite a long time trying to find the bit of code you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

`nameof` is a keyword, so you would need to look into the compiler for the source code of how it is processed. Fortunately for you, the C# compiler is now open-sourced under the [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/) project. Understanding a compiler is not a trivial task – source code is passed through pipelines of transformations, which each one adding more syntactic or semantic information. To start you off, the [`GetContextualKeywordKind`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/fab7134296816fc80019c60b0f5bef7400cf23ea/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxKindFacts.cs#L1192) parses the `nameof` keyword into a `SyntaxKind.NameOfKeyword`, which then gets matched in [`TryBindNameofOperator`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/4d2df4c8eff9ce8492dafe20b6bfb4012e4d0fa3/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Binder_Invocation.cs#L1482).

As to your other question of creating another such operator: Yes, you can, by cloning and modifying the Roslyn source. However, your new operator would obviously only work on the modified compiler, so you'd need to supply this to whoever will be compiling your code. This is something that's rarely done; you're normally better off defining extension methods for your custom functionality, unless you need something particularly esoteric.

Comment: Thank you Douglas and for the knowledge. This is very helpful. You answered my question to the point.